# JSF Managed Beans performance

Tags: java, jsf, managed-bean

I have a web page that has many forms. One for logging in, another for creating an article and another for submitting a comment. Now, each of these forms is backed by a different backing bean for instance: loggingBean, newCommentBean, etc. When the life cycle executes, does it create instances of each of these beans even though the user submitted only the "new comment" form?

Comment: I recommend read the excellent [BalusC's](http://stackoverflow.com/users/157882/balusc) blog post on the [JSF lifecycle](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/09/debug-jsf-lifecycle.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It all depends on the scope of the beans. Request beans are created once per request but you probably shouldn't worry about the overhead of a bean creation, it's tiny. You should usually be more concerned with beans staying around too long (session beans that should be request beans) which needlessly drains memory.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how you have the [scope](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/bean/package-summary.html) defined of the managed bean.

**EDIT** There is also the [eager](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/girch.html) attribute `@ManagedBean(eager = true)`  that you may find good to know.

> To force an application-scoped bean to
>   be instantiated and placed in the
>   application scope as soon as the
>   application is started and before any
>   request is made, the eager attribute
>   of the managed bean should be set to
>   true.